# BITCOUNT macro in C

Tags: c, macros, bit

how can I count how many zero bits are in variable?
I must use macro like thist BITCOUNT(x,c) where x is my variable and c is count of zero bits in x

example: X  = 00101001 and C = 5

Comment: I fail to see why `C` is supplied. Please clarify.

Comment: Have you considered a parity table (which usually count the number of *lit* bits in an octet, so you'll likely have an inverse-parity table instead).

Comment: `#define BITCOUNT(x,c) (c)`

Comment: @chris +1 nice. If `c` is indeed the number of zero-bits, `(c)` would be the right answer (though it begs the question where it *came from in the first place*. =P)

Comment: How about `#define BITCOUNT(x,c) for(int i=0,c=0;c+=!(x&1),i<sizeof(c)*8;x=x>>1,++i){}`?  Just off the top of my head and don't have a compiler handy to test it with, so not posted as an answer.  And of course it destroys x in the process.  (And yes, it can be written so it doesn't destroy `x` - see if you can figure out how).  Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution:

`#include <limits.h>`

```
#define BITCOUNT(x,c) \
    { \
        int i; \
        (c) = 0; \
        for ( i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x); i++ ) \
            (c) += ( (x) & ( 1 << i ) ) == 0; \
    }
```

Comment: Interesting, I never thought of `c` as an lvalue.

Comment: Well, `c` is supposed to have the number of zero bits.

Comment: This could need the funky do-while, and the constant 8 could be CHAR_BIT * sizeof x.

Comment: Thanks @wildplasser.  This is why I am on stackoverflow.  I just learned something.  If you replace `8` with `CHAR_BIT` in the `for` statement, you also need to `#include <limits.h>`

Comment: You are correct about the `<limits.h>`. BTW: you still assume `sizeof x == 1`

Comment: Yes, and that can be fixed by changing the `CHAR_BIT` in the loop header to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(x)`

Comment: @Magtheridon96: Done, and tested with an `int` as well.

Comment: `1 << i` can overflow (`1` is an `int`, if `CHAR_BIT * sizeof x` is not less than the width of `int`, it will overflow), better use `(x >> i) & 1` to avoid that [that can still invoke undefined behaviour if the type of `x` has padding bits, but that's a smaller risk].

Comment: <!-- language: c -->
#define BIT_COUNT(x,c) \
    do{ \
        int k =x; \
        for(int i=0;i<sizeof(x)*8;i++) \
        {\
            if((x%2)==0)\
                c++; \
            x = x >> 1; \
        } \
        x =k; \
    }while(0);

Comment: but why a macro?  They just make it harder to debug your code, and this doesn't buy you anything

Answer (score 0):

FYI, gcc has a builtin that does that:

```
__builtin_popcount()
```

( https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html )

I think that depending on your architecture, it could a nice performance boost.